# JSON querying through dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, numpy

Imagine you have 3 API responses:

```
test =  df['APIOutput'].apply(lambda url: requests.get(url, verify=False))

0    <Response [200]>
1    <Response [200]>
2    <Response [200]>
Name: APIOutput, dtype: object


type(test[0])

requests.models.Response
```

Now, I want to query each response on key in the dictionary for each response.

Came up with the following:

```
pprint.pprint(test.to_json()['data']['items'][0]['addresses'][0]['city'])
```

However, not working:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

desired output:

```
test['City']

Amsterdam
Deventer 
Rotterdam
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

I have no crystal ball, but I'd posit that you need a dictionary as the 'ApiOutput' column and not the request.get return value. Try changing:

> test =  df['APIOutput'].apply(lambda url: requests.get(url, verify=False))

to:

> test =  df['APIOutput'].apply(lambda url: requests.get(url, verify=False).json())

Let me know if it works.

Comment: this works well to convert it to a dict. However, when querying the data this turns into a key error

Comment: test['data'] KeyError: 'data' because it treats it as a column

Comment: I need to query this for each row: test['data']['items'][0]['addresses'][0]['city']. Can you help me?

Comment: for i, row in test.iteritems():
    df55[row] = test[i]['data']['items'][0]['addresses'][0]['city']

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `pprint` here. I suggest you move the request handling to a function, something like:

```py
def get_city(url):
  r = requests.get(url, verify=False)
  data = r.json()
  return data['data']['items'][0]['addresses'][0]['city']

df["city"] = df.APIOutput.apply(get_city)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'url'

Comment: @Max I misread your column name. It's `APIOutput`, not `url`. I fixed it.